# how to read a column with another column name in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have to read and process set of files.(eg: 100 files) In which one file come with a column name as 'Idass'. Other files come with the column name 'IdassId'.
After processing I select few columns and writing the output in excel.

```
df.to_excel(writer, columns=['Date','IdassId','TankNo','GradeNo','Sales'],sheet_name='sales')
```

Here I miss that single file's entry since it doesn't have column name as 'IdassId'. It contains that specific column with 'Idass'.
(I could not rename that column before processing since it is an automated process coming form another process).
I tried rename that column with IdassId and tried to write in excel.

```
d = {'Idass': 'IdassId'}
df.rename(columns=d).to_excel(writer, columns=['Date','IdassId','TankNo','GradeNo','Sales'],sheet_name='sales')
```

but above gives an error since another files come with same column name as 'idassId'

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

How to do this in pandas?

Comment: That's because that file also has a column `IdassId`. If you are certain that they are the same, you can just do `if 'Idass' in df.columns.values: df['IdassId'] = df['Idass']` and then write as usual.

Comment: @QuangHoang No , that particular file does not have 'IdaassId 'column. That has only 'Idass' column, which is equal to other files' ' IdassId' column. So, I need to pick that 'Idass' columns value as another Idassid in my final processed sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your concatenating the excel files together so it would look similar to below.

```
   Idass IdassId
0   0.0 NaN
1   1.0 NaN
2   2.0 NaN
3   3.0 NaN
4   4.0 NaN
5   NaN 0.0
6   NaN 1.0
7   NaN 2.0
8   NaN 3.0
9   NaN 4.0
```

If you were to rename Idass to IdassId then you would have two columns named IdassId and that is what is causing your error.

You should be able to fill in the null values of IdassID and get your desired result.

```
df['IdassId'] = df['IdassId'].where(df['IdassId'].notnull(), df['Idass'])
df.drop('Idass', axis=1, inplace=True)

    IdassId
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
5   0.0
6   1.0
7   2.0
8   3.0
9   4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your defined d{} is trying to rename Idass to IdassId. I think your key:value pairing is switched.

Comment: Yes, because other files contain 'Idassid' column. SO finally i want to pick 'IdassId' 'coulmn. But one file misses that. So i rename that Idass to IdassId. Is there better approach I can try?